# How to avoid error: name 'score history' is not defined in modules section in Python for absolute beginners by Mark Winerbottom

Tags: python, nameerror

I'm on the course Python for absolute beginners by Mark Winterbottom, the Modules Section.
I've made a follow-along task, and I literally followed every step, but it gives me an error Mark doesn't get.
Please, help.
Here is a full code (first Module part, and then the Script):

```
"""
Module for exam predictions. 
"""

def get_avg(score_histrory):
    """Takes a list of previous grades and returns average."""
    return sum(score_history) / len(score_history)

def predict_score(score_history, min_score=0):
    """Takes a list of previous persentage grades and returns the average."""
    score_avg = get_avg(score_history)
    if score_avg < min_score:
        return min_score 
    
    return score_avg 
"""
Functions for calculating results.
"""
A_THRESHOLD = 70
B_THRESHOLD = 60
C_THRESHOLD = 50
D_THRESHOLD = 40
E_THRESHOLD = 30 

def get_grade(score):
    """Accepts a score and returns a letter version."""
    if score >= A_THRESHOLD:
        return 'A'
    elif score >= B_THRESHOLD:
        return 'B'
    elif score >= C_THRESHOLD:
        return 'C'
    elif score >= D_THRESHOLD:
        return 'D'
    elif score >= E_THRESHOLD:
        return 'E'
    
    return 'F'

"""
Srcipt for proccessing students grades.
"""
from grades.predict import predict_score 
from grades.results import get_grade 

score_history = [5, 10, 10, 2]

predicted_score = predict_score(score_history)

predicted_grade = get_grade(predicted_score)
print(f'The students predicted grade is: {predicted_grade}')
```

NameError: name 'score_history' is not defined

Thanks a lot. It's my first time asking a question here. Hope for your support.

Comment: Fix it by actually naming the function parameter `score_history` instead of `score_histrory`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just have a typo in your code "histrory" and not "history":

```
def get_avg(score_history):
"""Takes a list of previous grades and returns average."""
    return sum(score_history) / len(score_history)
```

Comment: Oh, thanks a lot. I've checked several times for typo, and have really noticed it only now. Thank you!

Comment: no problem, don't hesitate to mark my answer as the solution